# Exception handling in reading excel files, C#

Tags: c#, excel, exception

I am fairly new to C# coding, and recently I read that it is better to use `Try Catch` than `if/else` for file I/O related matters. I also read in other threads that `try catch` block should be avoided in loops because they significantly lower performances.

In my case, I am reading multiple (often over 1,000) excel files using for loop. Currently, I am using if/else if to handle really basic exceptions (i.e. file exist or not), but I was thinking of implementing try catch for the reason I explained above.

Here's some of my code

```
public void ReadFile(string path)
        {
            Excel.Application xlApp;
            Excel.Workbooks xlBooks;
            Excel.Workbook xlBook;
            Excel.Worksheet xlSheet;

            xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            xlBooks = xlApp.Workbooks;
            xlBook = xlBooks.Open(path);
            xlSheet = xlBook.Sheets[1];

            int rowCount = FindLastRow(xlSheet);
            int colCount = FindLastColumn(xlSheet);

            string header = "";

            string glNum = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path).Trim();
            for (int row = 1; row <= rowCount; row++)
            {
                bool processDone = false;
                string curationInfo = "";
                List<string> data = new List<string>();
                // If empty line, skip
                if (IsEmpty(xlSheet, row, colCount)) continue;
                // If header line, capture
                if (IsHeader(xlSheet, row, colCount) != "")
                {
                    header = IsHeader(xlSheet, row, colCount);
                    continue;
                }
                // If coloured line, capture
                if (IsColoured(xlSheet, row, colCount))
                {
                    curationInfo = ConstructCurationInfo(xlSheet, row, colCount);
                    data.Add(curationInfo);
                    // If last row, end
                    if (row == rowCount) processDone = true;
                    while (!processDone)
                    {
                        // If last row
                        if (row == rowCount)
                        {
                            // If last row is empty, one section is done
                            if (IsEmpty(xlSheet, row, colCount)) processDone = true;
                            // If last row is header, one section is done
                            else if (IsHeader(xlSheet, row, colCount) != "") processDone = true;
                            // Every other case
                            else
                            {
                                // if coloured, capture
                                if (IsColoured(xlSheet, row, colCount))
                                {
                                    string newCurationInfo = ConstructCurationInfo(xlSheet, row, colCount);
                                    data.Add(newCurationInfo);
                                }
                                processDone = true;
                            }
                        }
                        // If not last row
                        else
                        {
                            int nextRow = row + 1;
                            // If next row is last row, end
                            if (nextRow == rowCount) processDone = true;
                            // If next row is empty, one section is done
                            if (IsEmpty(xlSheet, nextRow, colCount)) processDone = true;
                            // If next row is header, one section is done
                            else if (IsHeader(xlSheet, nextRow, colCount) != "") processDone = true;
                            // Every other case
                            else
                            {
                                // if coloured, capture
                                if (IsColoured(xlSheet, nextRow, colCount))
                                {
                                    string newCurationInfo = ConstructCurationInfo(xlSheet, nextRow, colCount);
                                    data.Add(newCurationInfo);
                                }
                                row++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (processDone && data.Count != 0)
                {
                    Curation cur = new Curation(header, data, glNum);
                    curationList.Add(cur);
                }
            }
            // Terminate background Excel Workers
            xlBook.Close(false, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
            xlBooks.Close();
            xlApp.Quit();
            xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlSheet);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlBook);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlBooks);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();
        }
```

And the Form method that uses ReadFile() method

```
// Background workers
        private void mergeNew_bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            string input_path = db_input_tb.Text;
            string output_dir_path = output_tb.Text;
            // Status message to be reported to the UI
            string status = "";

            status = "Collecting files to be read.....";
            mergeNew_bgw.ReportProgress(0, status);
            List<string> excelPaths = GetPathToExcel(input_path);

            if (IsEmpty(excelPaths))
            {
                status = "No File to be Processed!";
                mergeNew_bgw.ReportProgress(0, status);
                fileToProcess = false;
            }
            // If not empty list, process
            else
            {
                ExcelInfo info = new ExcelInfo();
                bool doesExist = false;
                string path = "";
                int row = 1;
                for (int i = 0; i < excelPaths.Count; i++)
                {
                    status = "Processing....." + (i + 1).ToString() + "/" + excelPaths.Count.ToString();
                    mergeNew_bgw.ReportProgress(0, status);
                    info.ReadFile(excelPaths[i]);
                    // If last file, write excel file
                    if (i + 1 == excelPaths.Count)
                    {
                        status = "Writing Complete Merged File";
                        mergeNew_bgw.ReportProgress(0, status);
                        info.WriteNew(ref doesExist, ref row, ref path, output_dir_path);
                        info.Clear();
                    }
                    else if ((i + 1) % cutoff == 0)
                    {
                        status = "Writing Partial Merged File";
                        mergeNew_bgw.ReportProgress(0, status);
                        info.WriteNew(ref doesExist, ref row, ref path, output_dir_path);
                        info.Clear();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Should I implement `try catch` block inside the for loop in mergeNew_bgw_DoWork method like this?

```
for (int i = 0; i < excelPaths.Count; i++)
            {
                status = "Processing....." + (i + 1).ToString() + "/" + excelPaths.Count.ToString();
                mergeNew_bgw.ReportProgress(0, status);
                try
                {
                    info.ReadFile(excelPaths[i]);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    throw new Exception(e.ToString());
                }
                finally
                {
                    // If last file, write excel file
                    if (i + 1 == excelPaths.Count)
                    {
                        status = "Writing Complete Merged File";
                        mergeNew_bgw.ReportProgress(0, status);
                        info.WriteNew(ref doesExist, ref row, ref path, output_dir_path);
                        info.Clear();
                    }
                    else if ((i + 1) % cutoff == 0)
                    {
                        status = "Writing Partial Merged File";
                        mergeNew_bgw.ReportProgress(0, status);
                        info.WriteNew(ref doesExist, ref row, ref path, output_dir_path);
                        info.Clear();
                    }
                }                   
            }
```

Thank you for your help!

#### EDIT

Apparently, performance will not change that much as pointed by one of the comments. However, where should I insert try catch block in order to get meaningful error messages? ReadFile() method is big, so I think putting the entire method in try block may not give users meaning error messages. Would it be better to insert try catch somewhere inside ReadFile() method?

Comment: You're using `Excel.Application`. Anything else you do will have no noticeable impact on the "performance" of your application.

Comment: @Blindy Hmm, alright. Could you possibly look at edited question? Thanks